# Google analytics, campaign attribution for app install

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

Google's documentation on campaign tracking is messy at best.

Is there a tutorial or sample (google sample doesn't include campaign attribution it seems) that shows how to set up campaign attribution?

For instance, doc says

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
    TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
// Set screen name.
t.setScreenName(screenName);

// In this example, campaign information is set using
// a url string with Google Analytics campaign parameters.
// Note: This is for illustrative purposes. In most cases campaign
//       information would come from an incoming Intent.
String campaignData = "http://examplepetstore.com/index.html?" +
    "utm_source=email&utm_medium=email_marketing&utm_campaign=summer" +
    "&utm_content=email_variation_1";

// Campaign data sent with this hit.
t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
    .setCampaignParamsFromUrl(campaignData)
    .build()
);
```

Obviously we only want to report the install only once, but how can I do that? doc doesn't say where we should place the code.

Comment: did you succeed to know how & where to set the campaign data ?

Comment: no, I concluded google's support is very weak on this subject, and turned to other solutions. google for 'deeplink' and you will find libraries other people use for this.